# Amazon SES bounce/complaint handling

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

Currently we are using Mandrill to send our emails, when ever Mandrill detects a bounce we get the original headers along with the bounce or a subaccount where the email was send from.

In Amazon SES we are getting the notifications through SNS thats no problem but besides the email from the user we get no original information back. So we have no idea what email campaign the user bounced on etc.

Anybody that knows how to handle this?

Comment: We are not sending spam, you may always get soft bounces if a users mailbox is full and decide not to send email for a couple of days. Users subscribe manually to our service but as this service runs in 35 countries we have 35 different lists sending from the same FROM domain. As we send 500.000 emails a day searching all lists for every delivery notification, complaint of bounce notification is just not smart enough. We want to be able to handle bounces to remove inactive mailboxes from our service i think people sending spam dont care about this at all.

Answer (score 0):

every SNS message contain a "mail" part with the messageId [see](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-examples.html). If you are sending a mail you receive as the only response the messageId [see](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html).
so I store all the messageId together with information I later maybe need if that mail bounces or gets complaints and if I receive a bounce I can query all the information with the given messageId.

Comment: how can you query using messageID to get bounce/delivery status?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression to get messageId
In python i use like this

```
message_id = re.findall(r"(\w+(?:-\w+)+)@email.amazonses.com", json.dumps(event))[0]
```

Similar thing you can try in php